# Nameserver always at the top in url bar in nginx (with no redirect)

Tags: php, nginx

My app has only two pages presented to the user, both in mobile or desktop. Firstly a login page and after the app page itself. When accessing `www.myapp.com` the user is firstly indexed towards the login page and if he is logged in he is then php redirected to the app page. Here is my server schema:

`root
index.php (login page)
     mobile/mobile.php
     profile/profile.php`

What I'd like is to avoid the user having `www.myapp.com/mobile/mobile.php`,`www.myapp.com/profile/profile.php` but instead `www.myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com/desktop` or `www.myapp.com/mobile`
so he can also switch between layouts. Unfortunately this is throwing a 404 error in my servers:

**nginx default file**:

```
 location ~ /mobile/mobile.php$ {
    rewrite $host/mobile break;
 }   

 location ~ /index.php$ {
    rewrite $host break;
 }   

 location ~ profile/profile.php$ {
    rewrite $host/desktop break;
 }
```

Should it be something like this or should it be another complete way? **I'd like to do this in my server, not in the user device...** Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic for SO, but in any case you did it exactly backwards. You want to `rewrite` the user-visible URL to the backend URL, not the other way around. Then when you send the user to `/mobile`, nginx will translate it to `/mobile/mobile.php` and PHP can execute it.

Comment: @hobbs could you give a coded example please? I understand your logic but not the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was tested on my development server:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    root /usr/local/www/test;
    index index.php;

    location = /mobile { rewrite ^ /mobile/; }
    location = /desktop { rewrite ^ /profile/; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /mobile {
        index mobile.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /profile {
        index profile.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    php;
    }   
}
```

It uses `index` and `try_files` to find your scripts and then internally redirect to the `fastcgi` handler. I have `upstream php { ... }` defined elsewhere. You might employ rewrite rules and the `internal` directive to enforce the scheme of no php script on the URL bar.

The mobile rewrite is simply to maintain consistency with the desktop rewrite, so that the client doesn't see a trailing `/`.

This is just one example of a multitude of solutions. Typically, there are ancillary files (css, js, images) with their URLs that also need to be accommodated.

Comment: This is not working at all... did you understand my original request? This only throws a 404...

Comment: Nevermind, it did! Thank you so much! Only one problem... it works with the mobile directive... but fails with desktop which I have like this (check my question for the server folder structure):

`location /desktop {
     index profile/profile.php
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}`

This throws a 404 error. How exactly could I change that?

Comment: @Fane Oops! Sorry. I have adjusted the example.